# what are difference between get_terms() and get_categories() in wordpress. I have a get_category and get_terms as follows

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

what are difference between get_terms() and get_categories() in wordpress.  I have a get_category and  get_terms as follows
get_categories array of object

```
array(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 2
            [name] => Breakfast
            [slug] => breakfast
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
            [taxonomy] => menu_category
            [description] => hello word
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 2
            [category_count] => 4
            [category_description] => hello word
            [cat_name] => Breakfast
            [category_nicename] => breakfast
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => Dinner
            [slug] => dinner
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
            [taxonomy] => menu_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 4
            [category_count] => 4
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Dinner
            [category_nicename] => dinner
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [2] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [name] => Lunch
            [slug] => lunch
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
            [taxonomy] => menu_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 3
            [category_count] => 4
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Lunch
            [category_nicename] => lunch
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
get_terms array of object

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 2
            [name] => Breakfast
            [slug] => breakfast
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
            [taxonomy] => menu_category
            [description] => hello word
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => Dinner
            [slug] => dinner
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
            [taxonomy] => menu_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [2] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [name] => Lunch
            [slug] => lunch
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
            [taxonomy] => menu_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

Yes I tried my way but I don't understand what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_categories()` is a [wrapper function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) for `get_terms('category')`.

Being that `get_terms()` is the main function it has a few more arguments that can be passed to it.

In general wordpress has quite a few wrapper functions that make for less coding per se, but if you want full control you can use the main function. A lot of them take similar arguments and return the same things with little difference.